# What to put in web.config to overcome 404.19 error

Tags: iis, web-config, http-status-code-404

I have a vb.net program that is called as part of a payment authoristation process.  It receives a GET parameter.

If the contents of the parameter includes the text 0x anywhere then I get a 404.19 error.

I have no control over what is put in the GET parameter. I can restrict whatever I do to be applicable to calls from just one site.

I think I need to alter the filtering rules but I obviously want to take care not to leave my site vulnerable in any other way.

I have no access to IIS console and must handle this with web.config.

Please can somebody tell me what to put in the web.config.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules/ Only when your server administrators allow you to override request filtering rules, you can do that via web.config. So your only option is to contact them and discuss.

Comment: 404.19 come from request filter module. So you could just override these section via <clear/> and set your own rule in section system.webServer/security/requestFiltering in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from request filtering. Put the below code in web.config to clear all previous filtering rules. This will solve the problem.

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
          <filteringRules>
             <clear />
          </filteringRules>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```